# Mysql JSON output using json_object

Tags: mysql, json

I have been hacking at this for days now and just cannot get the final piece of the puzzle working....

The problem seems to get a nested object with 2 nested objects at the same level?

I need to get an output as follows:

```json
{
  "Id": "19115",
  "ClassScheduleId": "2143",
  "MaxCapacity": "30",
  "WebCapacity": "20",
  "TotalBooked": "0",
  "TotalBookedWaitlist": "0",
  "WebBooked": "0",
  "SemesterId": null,
  "IsCanceled": "0",
  "Substitute": "0",
  "Active": "1",
  "IsWaitlistAvailable": "0",
  "IsEnrolled": "0",
  "HideCancel": "0",
  "IsAvailable": "0",
  "StartDateTime": "2021-09-06T09:15:00+02:00",
  "EndDateTime": "2021-09-06T10:15:00+02:00",
  "LastModifiedDateTime": "2021-09-07T02:35:21+02:00",
  "StaffId": "100000237",
  "BookingStatus": "PaymentRequired",
  "VirtualStreamLink": null,
  "ClassDescription": {
    "Id": "257",
    "Active": "0",
    "Description": "<div>Designed to burn calories while toning and lengthening, this challenging class mixes intense, high-impact cardio and plyometric training with full body conditioning and yoga. Using popular and motivating music, this fast-paced, high energy class will help create that long and lean look. No class is ever the same to ensure progressive results</div>",
    "LastUpdated": "2021-08-17T15:31:21+02:00",
    "Name": "Bottoms Up",
    "Notes": "",
    "Prereq": "",
    "Program": {
      "Id": "26",
      "Name": "Classes",
      "ScheduleType": "Class",
      "CancelOffset": "0"
    },
    "SessionType": {
      "Id": "207",
      "Type": "All",
      "Name": "Spinning",
      "NumDeducted": "1",
      "ProgramId": "26"
    }
  }
}
```

My last attempt, which I think is "close" is just not working and throwing an error :-(

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'ClassScheduleId', c.ClassScheduleId,
                'MaxCapacity', c.MaxCapacity,
                'WebCapacity', c.WebCapacity,
                'TotalBooked', c.TotalBooked,
                'TotalBookedWaitlist', c.TotalBookedWaitlist,
                'WebBooked', c.WebBooked,
                'IsCanceled', c.IsCanceled,
                'Substitute', c.Substitute,
                'Active', c.Active,
                'IsWaitlistAvailable', c.IsWaitlistAvailable,
                'IsEnrolled', c.IsEnrolled,
                'HideCancel', c.HideCancel,
                'Id', c.Id,
                'IsAvailable', c.IsAvailable,
                'StartDateTime', c.StartDateTime,
                'EndDateTime', c.EndDateTime,
                'LastModifiedDateTime', c.LastModifiedDateTime,
                'BookingStatus', c.BookingStatus
                'ClassDescription', json_object(
                    'Active', cd.Active,
                    'Description', cd.Description,
                    'Id', cd.Id,
                    'LastUpdated', cd.LastUpdated,
                    'Name', cd.Name,
                    'Notes', cd.Notes,
                    'Prereq', cd.Prereq,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(
                        'Program', json_object(
                            'Id', p.Id,
                            'Name', p.Name,
                            'ScheduleType', p.ScheduleType,
                            'CancelOffset', p.CancelOffset
                        ),
                        'SessionType', json_object(
                            'Type', st.Type,
                            'Id', st.Id,
                            'Name', st.Name,
                            'NumDeducted', st.NumDeducted,
                            'ProgramId', st.ProgramId
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
FROM Classes as c
LEFT JOIN ClassDescription as cd ON cd.Id = c.ClassDescriptionId
LEFT JOIN Program as p ON p.Id = cd.ProgramId
LEFT JOIN SessionType as st ON st.Id = cd.SessionTypeId
```

Any ideas where I can get better documentation or an SQL visual editor that has the capability to format/build these types of queries?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Did you try JSON_PRETTY native function?
Doc here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-utility-functions.html

Comment: Hello, I did check out JSON_PRETTY but it seems to be more for very basic output and gets "ugly" when you want to build complex JSON objects. The example I have above is 30% of the final JSON OBJECT so it will get messy using json_pretty.

So in my example I can get everything done apart from getting the "Program" and "SessionType" elements inside of "ClassDescription"

Answer (score 1):

Bingo!!! Devil is always in the detail

Seems I missed the , after 'BookingStatus', c.BookingStatus and I also removed the GROUP_CONCAT!

This works perfect!

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'ClassScheduleId', c.ClassScheduleId,
                'MaxCapacity', c.MaxCapacity,
                'WebCapacity', c.WebCapacity,
                'TotalBooked', c.TotalBooked,
                'TotalBookedWaitlist', c.TotalBookedWaitlist,
                'WebBooked', c.WebBooked,
                'IsCanceled', c.IsCanceled,
                'Substitute', c.Substitute,
                'Active', c.Active,
                'IsWaitlistAvailable', c.IsWaitlistAvailable,
                'IsEnrolled', c.IsEnrolled,
                'HideCancel', c.HideCancel,
                'Id', c.Id,
                'IsAvailable', c.IsAvailable,
                'StartDateTime', c.StartDateTime,
                'EndDateTime', c.EndDateTime,
                'LastModifiedDateTime', c.LastModifiedDateTime,
                'BookingStatus', c.BookingStatus,
                'ClassDescription', json_object(
                    'Active', cd.Active,
                    'Description', cd.Description,
                    'Id', cd.Id,
                    'LastUpdated', cd.LastUpdated,
                    'Name', cd.Name,
                    'Notes', cd.Notes,
                    'Prereq', cd.Prereq,
                        'Program', json_object(
                            'Id', p.Id,
                            'Name', p.Name,
                            'ScheduleType', p.ScheduleType,
                            'CancelOffset', p.CancelOffset
                        ),
                        'SessionType', json_object(
                            'Type', st.Type,
                            'Id', st.Id,
                            'Name', st.Name,
                            'NumDeducted', st.NumDeducted,
                            'ProgramId', st.ProgramId
                        )
                    )
            )
        )
FROM Classes as c
LEFT JOIN ClassDescription as cd ON cd.Id = c.ClassDescriptionId
LEFT JOIN Program as p ON p.Id = cd.ProgramId
LEFT JOIN SessionType as st ON st.Id = cd.SessionTypeId
```